# Why does -[NSPasteboard readObjectsForClasses:options:] return only 1 item from a drag?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nspasteboard

I'm writing a number of objects to NSPasteboard for a drag operation using `beginDraggingSessionWithItems:event:source:`:

```
NSMutableArray *draggingItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    NSPasteboardItem *pasteboardItem = [NSPasteboardItem new];

    [pasteboardItem setDataProvider:[MyItem itemForIndex:i]
                           forTypes:@[@"com.test.FooType"]];

    NSDraggingItem *draggingItem = [[NSDraggingItem alloc] initWithPasteboardWriter:pasteboardItem];
    // ...
    [draggingItems addObject:draggingItem];
}

[sourceView beginDraggingSessionWithItems:draggingItems
                                    event:theEvent
                                   source:self];
```

And in the dragging destination (in the same app), I try to receive these items using `readObjectsForClasses:options:`, but I only receive one of them.

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    // sender.draggingPasteboard.pasteboardItems contains all items

    NSArray *myItems = [sender.draggingPasteboard readObjectsForClasses:@[[MyItem class]] options:nil];
    // pasteboard:item:provideDataForType: is called for each object on the pasteboard...
    // ...but this method only returns 1 object (the first one)??
```

(Note that if you pass `@[[NSPasteboardItem class]]` for the classes, you get all items back unmodified.)

Any idea why this would this happen? [Sample project available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/62ad2ar5p01wd4u/DragTest.zip?dl=0) (with lots of NSLogs to see that the items are actually being written to the pasteboard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the implementation of `-pasteboard:item:provideDataForType:` needs to set data **on the item**, not on the pasteboard — doing the latter overwrites previously written data for other items.